# How to create a 2D matrix of integer in c# (mvvm)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, integer

I want to create my own matrix class of integers.

in this class, i would fill automatically one part of my matrixes (all my matrixes will be symetric), update their size (add or remove), get their size.

Actually my code is :

```
public class MachineMatrix
    {
        private int size;
        private int[,] matrix;


        public MachineMatrix(int size)
        {
            this.size = size;
            this.matrix=new int[this.size,this.size];
        }


        public void FillMatrix()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < this.getSize()-1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = i; j < this.getSize() - 1; j++)
                {
                    if (this.matrix[i, j] == 0)
                        matrix[i, j] = matrix[j, i];
                    else
                        matrix[j, i] = matrix[i, j];
                }
                matrix[i, i] = 0;
            }
        }

        public MachineMatrix UpgradeSize(MachineMatrix mat, int nbSize)
        {
            int newSize = mat.getSize() + nbSize - 1;
            MachineMatrix m = new MachineMatrix(newSize);
            for (int i = 0; i < mat.getSize() - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < mat.getSize() - 1; j++)
                {
                    m[i, j] = mat[i, j];
                }
                for (int j = mat.getSize(); j<m.getSize()-1 ; j++)
                {
                    m[i, j] = 0;
                }
            }
            for (int i = mat.getSize(); i < m.getSize() - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = mat.getSize(); j < m.getSize() - 1; j++)
                {
                    m[i, j] = 0;
                }
            }
            return m;
        }


        public int getSize() { return this.size; }
    }
```

My probleme is here :

***Cannot apply indexing with int[] to an expression of type 'my-project.Models.MachineMatrix'***

```
           m[i, j] = mat[i, j];

            m[i, j] = 0;

            m[i, j] = 0;
```

Comment: Maybe i done error in my class : structure errors or other else ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution :-D

```
m.matrix[i, j] = mat.matrix[i, j];
m.matrix[i, j] = 0;
m.matrix[i, j] = 0;
```

But now, my problem is to display it...